# How can I get Time Zone Region from SQLPLUS?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am using Oracle Developer and Oracle 11g (Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production)

```
select SESSIONTIMEZONE from DUAL;
```

Result in SQLPLUS/system_config_tbl_load.sql:  -4:00
 Result in SQL Developer:                       America/New_York

gives different results in SQL Developer and SQLPLUS.
I want to see the region in SQLPLUS.

Additionally I have to do this for multiple locations and do not have the option of changing the Time Zone using "ALTER SESSION SET time_zone = 'America/New_York'"

Answer (score 0):

I assume SQL Developer makes an implict `ALTER SESSION SET time_zone=...` when you open a new connection.

I see several solutions:

- Define environment variable `TZ` on client host
- Create a database trigger and set timezone accordingly
- Change the timezone of the database - works unless any user sets his personal timezone

Database Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LOG_T_LOGON 
   AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
DECLARE

BEGIN
   IF ora_login_user IS NULL THEN 
      RETURN;
   END IF;
   IF ora_login_user IN (...) THEN -- Prevent to be executed for EACH user
      execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET time_zone = ''America/New_York''';
   END IF;
END;
```

END;

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not work for me.  Since this needs to be run at multiple locations and I can not write a different function for each.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function in your application or in this trigger like this:

```
IF SESSIONTIMEZONE = '-4:00' THEN
   execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET time_zone = ''America/New_York''';
ELSIF SESSIONTIMEZONE = '-5:00' THEN
   execute immediate ...
END IF;
```

Comment: This does not work either because there are multiple regions associated with the offset (i.e -4:00, -5:00).  Also the following statement can be used for this:  SELECT distinct tzname, tz_offset(tzname) FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES order by tzname;

Comment: Then it's getting difficult, you want to set timezone to (for example) 'America/New_York' but you don't want/can set it on client location. In german we say to this: "Wash my coat but don't make me wet." - It's contradictory.

Comment: I might end up writing a Java Stored Procedure to obtain this data from the OS, if there is no direct way from Oracle.  On a side note - may be "dry cleaning" would work for the coat.