# How do sessions get their initial timezone

Tags: oracle, timezone, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

When I check the session timezone in **SQL developer** with

```
select sessiontimezone from dual;
```

I get `'Europe/Berlin'`. When I do the same in **SQL*Plus** I get `'+02:00'`.

This makes a difference when dealing with `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIMEZONE`, as Germany is sometimes in timezone UTC+01 and sometimes in UTC+02 due to daylight saving time. (Currently it's in UTC+02.)

How do the two tools get / set (?) their default timezones?

System information:

- Connections are via TNS.
- SQL Developer: 18.1.0.095.1630
- Oracle DBMS: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
- Operating system server: x86_64/Linux 2.4.xx
- Operating system client: Microsoft Windows 10 Professional

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/23120840/1509264 ?

Comment: Also see: [How to change the timezone of Oracle SQL Developer / Oracle Data Modeler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14864015/1509264)

Comment: @MT0: Thank you, I didn't see this first thread. Anyway, ... So Wernfried Domscheit supposes that SQL Developer executes an `ALTER SESSION SET time_zone = ...`. That may be right. But where does it take the region from? From the Windows OS? And as to SQLPlus, where does that tool take the timezone from? From the server operating system? Or are there some Oracle settings taking place? I'm still curious :-) The second thread I did see, but I don't want to know how I can change SQL Developer settings (actually I like its EUROPE/BERLIN zone better than SQLPlus's +02:00).

Comment: The second link was there not so much to tell you how to change the SQL Developer setting but to inform you that if it has been changed that the initial value will come from the `sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf` configuration file which will, in turn, be used to set a Java VM property. I still haven't found any documentation for where the initial value comes from (if it is not explicitly set in the config file) but my initial assumption is from the operating system (and you should be able to test that by changing the OS's timezone).

Comment: @MT0: Thank you, again. Sorry, you are right about checking the configuration file and I actually did so earlier. There is nothing in it to alter the time zone. And yes, I should be able to change my Windows region and see what happens. I'll do this later and post my result here. (I can't do that for the server's region though.)

Comment: @MT0: That was a good idea. It shows that SQL Developer pulls the Windows region when I open the tool. It then uses this timezone then for any session that I open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006728) list only the environment variable `ORA_SDTZ`.

However, it is taken from following settings:

- Registry Key `HKCU\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{Oracle Home Name}\ORA_SDTZ`
- Registry Key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{Oracle Home Name}\ORA_SDTZ`

  (resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_{Oracle Home Name}\ORA_SDTZ`)
- Environment variable `ORA_SDTZ`
- Current locale settings of your machine (most likely).
- Database time zone if none from above is found (just an assumption)

Your client application may have some additional sources for session time zone, see [How to change the timezone of Oracle SQL Developer / Oracle Data Modeler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864015/how-to-change-the-timezone-of-oracle-sql-developer-oracle-data-modeler) as example.

Environment variable should have the highest precedence.

Comment: Thank you. So Oracle looks first for HKCU, then HKLM and so on till it finds a setting. As I don't have any of the ORA_SDTZ set, the server's timezone is used ("Current locale settings of your machine"). I see. The SQL Developer on the other hand applies the Windows timezone, as I don't have an overriding entry in sqldeveloper.conf. Hence the difference. Thank you.